# symbol table not found debugging python + C

Tags: python, c, debugging, gdb

I have a C module, I compiled it with -g option, Now I am using some of the functions of this module using a python script. When I run this command -

```
gdb -ex r -args python test.py
```

it shows-

```
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/python2.7...Reading symbols from /usr/bin/python2.7...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

and while using GDB command list it throws -

```
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
```

what could be the potential reason..?

Comment: I don't think `gdb` know about python script. when you give `gdb -ex r -args python test.py` then it will go for debug `python` compiler not script.

Answer (score 0):

> what could be the potential reason..

The reason is that `/usr/bin/python2.7` was compiled without debug symbols, and your C module has not yet been dynamically loaded.

One way to deal with this is to set a deferred breakpoint on your module initialization code. Once you hit that breakpoint, `list` will start working.